# I want to know the grammatical label for one of the following words in a sentence

Tags: grammar

> "Swimming is one of the healthiest **exercises**."

In the above example if SWIMMING is subject please let me know what grammatical label can be given to the word "exercises"

Answer (score 1):

It's an "object of a preposition".

Answer (score 1):

It is a plural noun.

It is part of the phrase "one of the healthiest exercises", which is the subject complement of "swimming".

Within the phrase, "one" is a noun, which is modified by a prepositional phrase "of the healthiest exercises".  So "exercises" is the object of the preposition "of".